# Selenium - why doesn't thread.sleep work in safari?

Tags: java, selenium

In FireFox, I am able to slow down selenium using `Thread.sleep(xx)` but I can't slow it down in Safari. Please don't recommend me about wait till element is found.

Here is a user who faced the same issue: http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-51526.html

It honestly didn't see anything useful.

Also few other basic stuff like `name_of_input_box.clear()` aren't working on safari. Why are they behaving so?

Even basic code like the following is breaking (in safari , not firefox):

```
log("Searching for input box");
WebElement emailInput = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
        .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By
                .name("email")));
log("Clearing email input box");

emailInput.clear();
log("Sending keys " + email + " to the input box");
emailInput.sendKeys(email);
```

The point where my code is breaking:

```
emailInput.clear();
```

Here is a warning messgae if I put try catch loop around it

Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated

Here are my logs:

```
Searching for Input box
Clearing email input box
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use "wait till element is found?"  In all likelihood, Thread.Sleep isn't going to work, as you have already pointed out, so you must be open to other solutions, right?  Or do you just want to know why it doesn't work?

Comment: I am interested in knowing why it doesn't work at the moment :) . I have to obviously switch my ways cause I didn't think about it earlier but I am curious about the WHY. Its funny it just ignored it instead of ending the program.

Comment: I'm not sure we're here to explain the *why*, unless it leads to a solution.  Show us the code that is leading to the problem.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, which says: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)*

Comment: Alright! I understand no worries. I edited it to make it a programming oriented question

Comment: You still haven't told us why you don't want to use wait.until.  Also, I don't see a `Thread.sleep()` in your code.

Comment: Oh no. I already switched to wait until. I was hoping for an answer why it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure the web page is actually loading properly in safari? have you tried using visibilityOfElementLocated instead of presenceOfElementLocated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to click on the element before clearing it.